# powershell pipeline object to function

Tags: powershell

Here's the stub of what I'm trying to do:

```
function Set-test {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
               ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [object[]]$inputObject
    )
    Write-Verbose "Set-test: input obj= $inputObject" 

    PROCESS {
        foreach ($obj in $inputobject) {
            Write-Output $obj
        }
    }   
}

function Get-test {
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "swName" -Value "banana"
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Version" -Value "3.2.2"
    Write-Output "obj = $obj"
    $obj | Set-test -verbose    
}
```

Here's the output:

```
PS > Get-test
obj = @{swName=banana; Version=3.2.2}
VERBOSE: Set-test: input obj= 
Get-Process : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Name' because its argument is  specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\mytool\mytools.psm1:204 char:13
+     PROCESS {
+             ~
+ CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

As seen from the verbose output it appears that the object is not being piped to the function and it has me baffled.

Comment: Just a quick tip. Please have a look at a technique called splatting that is a better solution than your way of creating objects in your function "Get-test".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have that write-verbose in the set-test outside of a begin{}, process{} or end{} block.  It's messing things up.  If you move it inside the process{} block it works fine.

Comment: Spot on! Be aware though, that `$inputObject` will behave differently inside the `Process` block, depending on whether the input was supplied through the pipeline or as a parameter